# (create-react-app) Auto-reset countdown timer once reaches target date

Tags: reactjs, timer

I am trying to make a countdown timer for Christmas and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTWJypbcSLI&ab_channel=Olli) useful. It uses React with Day.js package. It works well if I set Christmas date timestamp manually. However, there are two target functions that I can't figure out.

1. Make timer disappear and display "Christmas today" on screen for 24 hours once it reaches the day of Christmas.
2. Automatically set new timeStampDayJs to next Christmas once current date reaches Dec. 26?

Currently, I have to set the next Christmas timestamp manually once Christmas arrives, and I can't automatically show "Christmas today" on the day of Christmas. Is there any way I can achieve the two goals automatically?

My code here (mostly the same as the YouTube video, but I set Christmas timestamp manually):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dayJs from "dayjs";
var utc = require("dayjs/plugin/utc");
var timezone = require("dayjs/plugin/timezone");
dayJs.extend(utc);
dayJs.extend(timezone);

const defaultRemainingTime = {
  seconds: "00",
  minutes: "00",
  hours: "00",
  days: "00",
};

const Countdown = () => {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(defaultRemainingTime);

  const countdownTimeStamp = 1671919200000;

  const getRemainingTime = (countdownTimeStamp) => {
    const timeStampDayJs = dayJs(countdownTimeStamp).tz("Europe/Helsinki");
    const nowDayJs = dayJs().tz("Europe/Helsinki");
    if (timeStampDayJs.isBefore(nowDayJs)) {
      return defaultRemainingTime;
    }

    return {
      seconds: getRemainingSeconds(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
      minutes: getRemainingMinutes(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
      hours: getRemainingHours(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
      days: getRemainingDays(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
    };
  };

  const getRemainingSeconds = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
    const seconds = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "seconds") % 60;
    return padWithZeros(seconds, 2);
  };

  const getRemainingMinutes = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
    const minutes = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "minutes") % 60;
    return padWithZeros(minutes, 2);
  };

  const getRemainingHours = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
    const hours = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "hours") % 24;
    return padWithZeros(hours, 2);
  };

  const getRemainingDays = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
    const days = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "days");
    return days;
  };

  const padWithZeros = (number, minLength) => {
    const numberString = number.toString();
    if (numberString.length >= minLength) {
      return numberString;
    } else {
      return "0".repeat(minLength - numberString.length) + numberString;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      updateRemaninigTime(countdownTimeStamp);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [countdownTimeStamp]);

  const updateRemaninigTime = (countdownTimeStamp) => {
    setRemainingTime(getRemainingTime(countdownTimeStamp));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{remainingTime.days} </span>
      <span>days </span>
      <span>{remainingTime.hours} </span>
      <span>hours </span>
      <span>{remainingTime.minutes} </span>
      <span>minutes </span>
      <span>{remainingTime.seconds} </span>
      <span>seconds </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Countdown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use two function to make your goals!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dayJs from "dayjs";
var utc = require("dayjs/plugin/utc");
var timezone = require("dayjs/plugin/timezone");
dayJs.extend(utc);
dayJs.extend(timezone);

const defaultRemainingTime = {
  seconds: "00",
  minutes: "00",
  hours: "00",
  days: "00",
  initialValue: true,
};

const Countdown = () => {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(defaultRemainingTime);  

  function getNextChristimaDay(){
    let today = dayJs().tz("Europe/Helsinki");
    let christmasYear = today.year();

    if (today.month() == 11 && today.day() > 25) {
      christmasYear = christmasYear + 1;
    }

    let christmasDate = new Date(christmasYear, 11, 25);
    const christmasDateTimeStamp = 
     Math.round(christmasDate.getTime());
    return christmasDateTimeStamp;    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRemainingSeconds = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
        const seconds = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "seconds") % 60;
        return padWithZeros(seconds, 2);
    };

    const getRemainingMinutes = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
    const minutes = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "minutes") % 60;
    return padWithZeros(minutes, 2);
    };

    const getRemainingHours = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
    const hours = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "hours") % 24;
    return padWithZeros(hours, 2);
    };

    const getRemainingDays = (nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs) => {
    const days = timeStampDayJs.diff(nowDayJs, "days");
    return days;
    };

    const padWithZeros = (number, minLength) => {
    const numberString = number.toString();
    if (numberString.length >= minLength) {
        return numberString;
    } else {
        return "0".repeat(minLength - numberString.length) + numberString;
    }
    };

    const getRemainingTime = () => {
        const timeStampDayJs = dayJs(getNextChristimaDay()).tz("Europe/Helsinki");
        const nowDayJs = dayJs().tz("Europe/Helsinki");
                
        return {
          seconds: getRemainingSeconds(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
          minutes: getRemainingMinutes(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
          hours: getRemainingHours(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
          days: getRemainingDays(nowDayJs, timeStampDayJs),
        };
    };
    
    setInterval(() => {        
        setRemainingTime(getRemainingTime());
    }, 1000);
  }, [setRemainingTime]);

  function showMessage(d, h, m, s){
    if(d <= 0 && h <= 0 && m <= 0 && s <= 0){
        return <span>Happy Christmas!</span>
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <span>{d}</span>
                <span>days </span>
                <span>{h}</span>
                <span>hours </span>
                <span>{m}</span>
                <span>minutes </span>
                <span>{s}</span>
                <span>seconds </span>
            </>
        )
    }
  }

  const { days, hours, minutes, seconds, initialValue } = remainingTime;
  
  return (
    <div>                   
        {!initialValue && showMessage(days, hours, minutes, seconds)}      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Countdown;
```

I remade your code and put two principals functions look above:

```
// this code you will use to discover the next Christmas day in timestamp, then you can not worry about the fixed timestamp value.

function getNextChristimaDay(){
  let today = dayJs().tz("Europe/Helsinki");
  let christmasYear = today.year();

   if (today.month() == 11 && today.day() > 25) {
    christmasYear = christmasYear + 1;
   }

   let christmasDate = new Date(christmasYear, 11, 25);
   const christmasDateTimeStamp = 
     Math.round(christmasDate.getTime());
    return christmasDateTimeStamp;    
 }


// In this step we resolved a problem with fixed text about remaning days or happy Christmas.
function showMessage(d, h, m, s){
    if(d <= 0 && h <= 0 && m <= 0 && s <= 0){
        return <span>Happy Christmas!</span>
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <span>{d}</span>
                <span>days </span>
                <span>{h}</span>
                <span>hours </span>
                <span>{m}</span>
                <span>minutes </span>
                <span>{s}</span>
                <span>seconds </span>
            </>
        )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That's informative! I compared with the new version and the original one and found that there is a 6-hr difference. Originally I set timer countdown based on Helsinki time (GMT+3 in summer and GMT+2 in winter), but the new version is based on my time zone (GMT+8). The ".tz("Europe/Helsinki")" doesn't seem to be working. Anyway I can fix this?

Comment: this happens because the function getNextChristimaDay was taking a current date from you localization, I replaced the code, creating a data based on "Europe/Helsinki". now I hope help you, if my anwser was usefull to you, plis consider vote with up vote

Comment: Sure, I did! I voted with up but got "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I then marked "accept the answer" with green check mark. Now I would like to test how it looks like when we are at or later than target date. I changed date to Jun. 23 on line 23 and 27 in the following git but the timer can't show up on screen. Is there any other thing I need to adjust?  gist link : https://gist.github.com/juifuhung/e645e2096d337d5813d5028e370f0057

Comment: The problem is because you have a if condition in function getRemainingTime, plis remove this and will be show happy christimas. ps: now you have more than 15 reputation hahah. I edited the answer

Comment: I tried to set the date on line 23 and 27  to 05/25 (or actually Jun 26, which is the date I am doing the test) and It worked! Thank you so much! But I can't check what happens if current date is later than reset date because  on it is based on the date object that checks current date on line 23, right?

Comment: Regarding the time zone, is it set on line 20 that says "let today = dayJs().tz("Europe/Helsinki");" ?